# Hide PHP Parameter from URL

Tags: php, forms, get

How can I hide the PHP `GET` parameters from a URL?

Here is how the URL looks like

```
../iar7.php?size1=&size=TURF&R3=R3&txtsize=&txttreadd=&small=&large=&smallsw=&largesw=&smallrc=&largerc=&scc=&lcc=&2t1=&2t2o=&2t3o=&2t1=1.36&2t2=1&2t3=5
```

I want to show only `../iar7.php`.

Comment: Make them POST parameters instead

Comment: I think we need more clarification on what you're trying to achieve. It's easy to make assumptions here.

Comment: although you had some follow up questions, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer since it fixed the problem you described in your original question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using a `GET`, all your payload will be shown as query params. If you would like to hide them perhaps try using a `POST` instead.

You can read up on some of the differences between the methods [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: here is what my form looks like `<form style=" margin-left: 10px;" id="vehicle" action="iar7.php" style="padding-left:30px;color:#fff">` so if edit that in to `<form Method='POST'  style=" margin-left: 10px;" id="vehicle" action="iar7.php" style="padding-left:30px;color:#fff">` will fix it?

Comment: simply add ``method='post'`` and it should send the parameters in the body instead of url!

Comment: I think you should mention that you need to use `$_POST` to obtain the query parameters.

Comment: as Willem mentioned, you will need to use ``$_POST`` to access the parameters by name, for example ``$_POST['size']``

Comment: @Pabs123  Yes that works but i have also use this  link on the page which takles you to the next page which still shows  `echo"<div id='link' style='color:#fff  '><a id='' style='color:#000;' href='iardetailt.php?sid=".$row['Auto_PN']."&i2t1=".$_REQUEST['2t1']."&i2t2=".$_REQUEST['2t2']."&i2t3=".$i2t3."&i2t4=".$i2t4."&smallrc=".$minrc."&largerc=".$maxrc."&rearsw=".$row['SW']."'>";echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Select</button>';echo"</div></td>"; How can i update that

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are asking. Instead of using href, set an onclick which submits the form which you have just updated, similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398726/using-the-post-method-with-html-anchor-tags)

Comment: I have three pages On the first page there is a form when i submit i get result in a table each result  has a link when you click on the link  takes you to the second page the link look like ` <a href='iardetailt.php?sid=".$row['Auto_PN']."&i2t1=".$_REQUEST['2t1']."&i2t2=".$_‌​REQUEST['2t2']."&i2t3=".$i2t3."&i2t4=".$i2t4."&smallrc=".$minrc."&largerc=".$maxr‌​c."&rearsw=".$row['SW']."'>";echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Select</button>';` When i put the `method='post'` fixes the url on the first page but how can i fix this May be changing `$_‌​REQUEST` to `$_‌​POST`?

Comment: `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` are used to access the request's content, so it will not alter how the information is sent. Try setting an onclick to post the form as mentioned in my last comment, otherwise there is not much you can do about an anchor using `GET`

Comment: There is no form to send after the fist form submit  i am creating a link based on the variables already submitted on the first one

Comment: If you already have all the variables, set up a form with hidden inputs and set up the anchor to submit this form using its ``onClick`` property. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get) is some more information on this technique, although I have already linked you to an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using forms, your html form would look like this:

```
<form method='post' action='/someurl'>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As already said before, there are two methods to send data: using [`GET`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) (which is encoded in the URL), or using [`POST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) which means the data is sended as additional payload in the HTTP request. You cannot hide the URL parameters from the GET request method, simply because it is the way GET is supposed to work.

You can do this by specifying this in your `<form>` tag in the HTML source code:

```
<form action='the.url.com/path/file.php' method='post'>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Furthermore I want to add that you have to note that in order to *process* the data in your PHP file, you will have to call [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) instead of [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).