# PHP Laravel SQL Delete and Update

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to delete and update records in my SQLite Database. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Functions seem to be fine, it's only my routes i'm having problems with.

I've tried many different methods, however i'm still having issues.

//update route

```
Route::post('update_item_action', function (Request $request) {
$form_content = $request->all();
$update = updatePost($form_content['id'], $form_content['description']);

return view(url("items.update_item"))->with('update', $update);
});
```

//delete route

Route::get('delete_item/{id}', function($id) {

```
$id = deletePost($id);



return redirect(url(""));
```

});

//delete function

function deletePost ($id) {

```
$sql = "delete from item where id = ?";

DB::delete($sql, array($id));
```

}

//update post

function updatePost ($id, $message) {

```
$sql = "update item set message = ? where id = ?";

DB::update($sql, array($message));
```

}

//html on update page

## Update Post

```
        <form method="post" action="{{url("update_item_action")}}">

            {{csrf_field()}}

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$item->id}}">

            <p>

                <label> Description </label>

                <input type="text" name="description" value="{{$item->description}}">

            </p>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">

        </form>
```

I'm simply trying to update my description, and delete the whole post.

Error for updating:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Thank you

Comment: you have problem with both `update` and `delete`?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Could you please edit your question and insert the code you wrote to call `delete_item/{id}`? This way we could help you with that error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue within your update method is you are requesting two arguments to be passed to function but you aren't defining them in route.

The route should look like this:

```php
Route::post('update_item_action/{id}/{message}', function($id, $message) {
    $update = updatePost($id, $message);
    return redirect(url("")) ->with ('update', $update);
});
```

If you want to retrieve the content of form, you should use `Request` class instance as function's argument:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // DO NOT USE Request FACADE

Route::post('update_item_action', function (Request $request) {
    $form_content = $request->all();
    $update = updatePost($form_content['id'], $form_content['description']);

    return redirect(url(""))->with('update', $update);
});
```

Take a look at Laravel's [request docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) on how to retrieve the content of the form or of the content of all requests sent to your server.

**Update**

Regarding delete route,

```html
<a class="delete" href="{{url("delete_item/$item->id")}}">Delete Item </a>
```

will send a GET request to server, but you are explicitly requesting that delete have to be done via POST request.
In this scenario you have two options: change the route definition to

```php
Route::get('delete_item/{id}', function($id) {
    /*etc..*/
});`
```

or making an async call to server using POST method, i.e. using jQuery, using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398726/using-the-post-method-with-html-anchor-tags), or any other you can find googling a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matteo,
I added in your recommended code, however i'm still getting errors.

Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/assignment/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php on line 205 and exactly 2 expected

Any more help would be more than appreciated.

Thank you kindly :)

Comment: Take a closer look to code I wrote in answer. I can assure you will work. I've just tried it and it returns correctly the response. If still doesn't work, update the question with your editings to code so I will take a look

Comment: Matteo, i love you... the delete works now, thanks to you. 
However, my update still isn't working. I added the relevant route, but still having no luck.

I'll update my code above.

Comment: You do not need to add a route, just edit the route you defined like I did in response and it will work

Comment: Apologies, i forgot to delete my old one. Only error i'm getting now is from using "all". 

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to write the right import. It's `Illuminate\Http\Request`. I will update the answer

Comment: I'm not getting anymore errors but the message isn't changing, it's staying the same

Comment: If problem is within database or queries, don't change the question but open another, otherwise the answer has no sense if the question changes