# How to hide the passing params in url using jsp page

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

```
<html>
<table border="1">
    <tr>

        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>Card No</th>
        <th>BANK</th>
        <th>PHONE NO</th>
        <th>PRIVATE KEY</th>
        <th>KEY</th>

    </tr></h3>
    <%
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/frodo", "root","");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from user ";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
         %>   
         <tr>
             <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(5) %></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(6) %></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(8) %></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(10) %></td>
             <td>
                 <a href ='generatekey.jsp?d=<%=rs.getString(1)%>&d2=<%=rs.getString(10)%>'>Generate</a>

             </td>
             </tr> 
            <%  
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
        {
           out.println(e);
        }
      %>
</table> 

And now the another jsp page which using these values is .......
 <%
    String id = request.getParameter("d");
    String pk = request.getParameter("d2");
  %>
```

Comment: Well, if you want to have `<a href="...">Generate</a>` link, you cannot hide the parameters. The `<a>` link sends GET request, so there is no other way to send parameters, than to add them in the URL. There are some workarounds, but you would have to use JavaScript, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398954/3511123

Comment: Btw. the JDBC code (`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` etc.) does not belong to JSP. Learn to use MVC pattern, you can start here: https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp

Comment: I am still a student. It is used for to do a project for academics. can you please suggest how to write a JavaScript  for that because i cant get how to write..@Jozef Chocholacek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of Joseph in the comments is completely right.

If you want to replace your `<a href link... >` that send a Get request, you have to replace it by a `<form>` + your destination url in the ‘action’ attribute and your parameters as hidden input field.
Here is the direct link to such an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398954/4444956
And replace the action attribute value with “generatekey.jsp” and the ‘d’ and ‘d2’ as input hidden fields (with their corresponding ds... value).